# DNS failover between internal and external addressing

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns

We have a multi branch office scenario where each office has an internet connection and a WAN VPN connection.

User machines/applications are configured for Exchange/Citrix via the FQDN and so available internally via the WAN connection and if the person was external to the business the setups also work via external DNS.

My issue is that if the WAN connection fails, the internal machines still try to go via the internal addressing and I'd like them to then go via the external addressing / internet connection but I'm not sure on the technique for this.

Conditional forwarders seem like they might be answer? Am I on the right track?

Putting a separate DNS record for the external IP in the internal DNS would then put it into round robin and I'm guessing cause more problems than it's worth as clients would see both? Can someone confirm?

Internal DNS:
mail.domain.com - resolves to internal IP 10.x.0.4
access.domain.com - resolves to internal IP 10.x.0.5

External DNS:
mail.domain.com - an external IP of the organisation
access.domain.com - an external IP of the organisation

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the DNS resolution is happening at each site correct? Which means even if the VPN is down, machines still resolve the hostname to local ip using the on site DNS Server? If so then i don't see any easy way of doing this. Conditional forwarders won't be much help in this scenario.

Comment: If you have your services on mail.domain.com set up such that it is internet accessible why not just use that across the board? It simplifies things greatly.

Comment: @Junaid - correct.

Comment: @TimBrigham - mainly for data traffic - we don't get charged data on the WAN connection, and we can also QoS it so that's preferred to the internet connection. Until the WAN connection isn't avail and it falls over ;(

Comment: Is there an alternate config to what we've done? What would the normal setup be?

Comment: OK think your comment about conditional forwarding may be the answer. Add a conditional forwarder on your brach office DNS Server for your domain and add TWO DNS servers to the list. First one being your main server at the head office (which is  over VPN) and second one being a public DNS server like your ISP DNS Server. That should fix your problem.

Comment: @Junaid So that will then roll to the second option if the first one isn't contactable? goodo!

Answer (score 0):

Using DNS no way to get what you want, because inherently DNS 
is several inert service.

You can try to implement the desired routing means:

1. Setup on brunch user machines connection to the external DNS name
   (resolvable to external ip)
2. Setup on brunch router custom route to each this external ip through your VPN connection (may be push it from your VPN server). Make sure that these routes only appear when connected VPN - other times brunch users will work through the internet.